# Uninstall Visual Studio 2013 with update 4

Tags: windows-7, installation, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I tried to install VS 2013 Community with update 4 via iso file on my Dell XPS L502 Windows 7 Premium laptop.

The installation is not going well since days and now the installer is stuck at

> configuring your system. This might take a while.

[image: Visual Studio installer]

It has been two days since the installer is stuck at this and the installer starts automatically when I boot up my system.

Now since I realised that app development for Windows 8 PC and phones is not possible on Windows 7 OS, I want to remove this Visual Studio installation from my PC.

However, I don't see Visual Studio or it's related components at Programs and Features window on Control Panel.

How can I remove Visual Studio installation?

Comment: It sounds like it has not installed anything.  What makes you think it has?  If the installer didn't finish, and it sounds like it didn't even start, then there is nothing to remove.

Comment: @Ramhound Opening the Start Menu, I can see Windows Phone 8.1 toolkit and Visual Studio 2013 application icon and folders. I opened VS 2013 and it launched as an installed software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. You can try running the installer with the `/uninstall /force` arguments.
2. Try this [Fix it](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/mats/program_install_and_uninstall/en). The page doesn't mention VS 2013 specifically but it might still help.
3. Reboot, try installing again and if it succeeds uninstall it.
4. Try something like Revo Uninstaller.
5. Last resort would be a manual search and clean-up of the files and registry keys/values.

Comment: I tried Revo Uninstaller, it launched the VS2013 uninstaller and did it's job.

Comment: Revo Uninstaller did this like a charm!

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to **Programmes and Features**
2. In the left bar look for **Uninstall an update**. In that window scroll down to find *Microsoft Visual Studio 2013*
3. Under that there will be two links: **Visual Studio 2013** and **Update 4**.
4. Click on **Update 4** and uninstall it first, then uninstall **Visual Studio 2013**.